# Rails route clash when using scopes and localization / i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes

In order to internationalize my app I would like to have named routes like 'hello_path' automatically translated to '/en/hello' or '/fr/bonjour" depending on the current I18n.locale. But I encounter a problem (name clash?):

My routes are:

```
LostInTranslation::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'  
  scope '/:locale' do
    constraints :locale => 'fr' do
      get 'bonjour' => 'home#hello', :as => 'hello'
    end
    constraints :locale => 'en' do
      get 'hello' => 'home#hello', :as => 'hello'
    end
  end
end
```

And in the ApplicationController I set the locale and pass it to the default url options:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_locale

  private

  def default_url_options(options={})
    options.merge({ :locale => I18n.locale })
  end

  def set_locale
    if params[:locale] and I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    else
      I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
    end
  end
end
```

But when in a view I use <%= link_to t('hello'), hello_path %> I get this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"home", :locale=>:fr, :action=>"hello"}
```

Yet rake routes says it is declared:

```
 root     /                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
hello GET /:locale/bonjour(.:format) {:locale=>"fr", :action=>"hello", :controller=>"home"}
hello GET /:locale/hello(.:format)   {:locale=>"en", :action=>"hello", :controller=>"home"}
```

Would you have any clue about why it's not working or another way to achieve this? I am  aware of the i18n_routing gem, but it works by declaring localized routes with different names (en_hello and fr_hello in this example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no experience with the I18n_routing gem but would imagine it accepts the non-localized route and translates it for you; for example you supply hello_path and it does the rest.

You should have a default language which isn't namespaced

```
 google.com     # english default locale
 google.com/es  # spanish
```

rather than

```
 google.com/en  # english
 google.com/es  # spanish
 google.com     # nothing here
```

You should check out the translate_routes gem which has default locales and which I've used without any problems. https://github.com/raul/translate_routes

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work similarly as i18n_routing, with helpers mapping edit_resource_path to edit_en_resource_path if :en is the current locale. But I thought it was possible to do it simply with the scope constraints I tried, so if anyone has a clue about this "No route matches" error I am still curious. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't know really. Wild guess but options.merge({ :locale => I18n.locale.to_s }) will remove the symbol.

Comment: Raul's translate_route was great, but it doesn't work with rails 3.1. I've been unable to make one of the forks that where supposed to be ok for 3.1 work.